# How to set a fix space between Row items

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a Row containing a small image followed by a Text. I'm trying to set **a fix space** between those 2 widgets (for the moment they are stuck one after the other). That should be something simple but I don't know a nice way to do it...

Here is my code:

```
  Widget displayRow(String imageName, String text, TextStyle textStyle) {
    Widget widget = Container(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0),
      color: Colors.green,
      child: Row (
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          Image.asset(
              "images/${imageName}",
              width: 32.0,
              height: 32.0,
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              fit: BoxFit.scaleDown
          ),

          Text(text, style: textStyle),
        ],
      ),

      height: 120.0,
    );

    return widget;
  }
```

I have put this code in a function because I intend to use it several times to display different rows all on the same pattern (an image + a text).

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `Container` with a relatively small `width`:

```
     Widget displayRow(String imageName, String text, TextStyle textStyle) {
  Widget widget = Container(
  margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0),
  color: Colors.green,
  child: Row (
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
    children: <Widget>[
      Image.asset(
          "images/${imageName}",
          width: 32.0,
          height: 32.0,
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          fit: BoxFit.scaleDown
      ),

      Container(width: 10.0), // You can adjust it to suit your design

      Text(text, style: textStyle),
    ],
  ),

    height: 120.0,
  );

  return widget;
}
```

You can also opt for wrapping the `Image` widget inside a `Container` and giving it a certain `padding` :

```
  Container(
   padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
   child: Image.asset(
          "images/${imageName}",
          width: 32.0,
          height: 32.0,
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          fit: BoxFit.scaleDown
      ),
  ),
```

Comment: In the meantime, I have seen that I can wrap the image in a container with margin. By this way, I can set the space on every sides of the image (so that it doesn't get stuck to the left border).

Comment: It'll also work, and you can use the `padding` property of your `Image`'s parent `Container`

Comment: Besides the above answer, this link was helpful to understand how to separate widgets. Docs => https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/layout#material-widgets